# Why exit_group flushes output buffer?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, system-calls, glibc

From the manual page I know that:

`exit()` flushes output buffers while `_exit`,`_Exit`,`exit_group` don't.

In the code below, the content of `test.log` will be `hello\nhello\n` only if `exit()` was called in child process, which is the same as I tested.

But when there's no statements in child process, it will behave like it's calling `exit()`, the content of `test.log` will be `hello\nhello\n` too.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{

    int pid;

    FILE *fp = fopen("test.log", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "hello\n");
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // do something
        ;
    }
    else
    {
        wait(NULL);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Through `ltrace` and `strace` I can see both parent and child called `exit_group`.

Since I called `exit` in parent, so it can be judged by using `ltrace` that `exit` will call `exit_group`.

But in the opposite I can't judge whether child process called `exit`.

Does gcc called `exit` in child process implicitly? It may be harmful to call `exit` in child process as many people said. If not, then why the buffer was flushed?

Testing gcc and glibc version:

- gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1)
- GNU C Library (Debian GLIBC 2.24-11+deb9u4) stable release version
  2.24

Comment: `return`ing from `main` is equivalent to `exit(mains_return_value);`. (Or you can think of `main` as being invoked via `exit(main(argc,argv));`).

Comment: @PSkocik Tested, This makes sense(if main's return type is void then the return code is ramdom). So it's programmer's responsibility to call `_exit`or`_Exit` explicitly in child process?

Comment: That or make sure output output buffers are empty/flushed before `fork()`ing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promoting PSkocik's comment to an answer:

Returning from `main` is always equivalent to calling `exit()`.  Either way is supposed to represent "normal" termination of a process, where you want for all the data you buffered to actually get written out, all `atexit()` cleanup functions called, and so on.

Indeed, the C library's startup code is often written simply as `exit(main(argc, argv));`

If you want the "harsher" effect of `_exit()` or `_Exit()` then you have to call them explicitly.  And a forked child process is a common instance where this is what you do want.

Comment: Well, a good alternative is to make sure all output buffers are fully flushed out before `fork()`ing.

Answer (score 0):

> But when there's no statements in child process, it will behave like it's calling exit(), the content of test.log will be hello\nhello\n too.

You have a statement in child process (implicit):

When child process returns from `main()`, the C runtime makes a call to `exit(0);` (or better, something equivalent to `exit(main(arc, argv, envp));`, indeed) that implies the flushing of buffers you are trying to avoid.

If you want to eliminate one of the `hello\n`s, just `fflush(fp);` *before calling to `fork()` system call*, as the call will duplicate `fp` in both processes, each with a partially full buffer the same way, and this is the reason you get the buffer contents duplicated.  Or better flush all output buffers with `fflush(NULL);`.